# UITableviewCell height not getting reset on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview which can be expanded on selecting the cell and collapses on selecting again. When you select, the cell should expand and display a label and when you select again it collapses and hides the label . The expanding and collapsing works fine, but if i scroll the tableview after expanding a cell it behaves weird. Once it goes out of the view and comes back , the cell will have the expanded cell's height but the label which is supposed to be shown in expanded cell is hidden.If i select the cell again it collapses and displays the label. I use ,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:t cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([self cellIsSelected:indexPath])
        return cell.frame.size.height+35;
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}

- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
    NSNumber *selectedIndex = [self.selectedIndexes objectForKey:indexPath];
    return selectedIndex == nil ? FALSE : [selectedIndex boolValue];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Deselect cell
    NSLog(@"Select cell:%@",indexPath);
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];

    if([self pickTaskForIndexPath:indexPath].productSpecialMessage){
        BOOL isSelected = ![self cellIsSelected:indexPath];
        NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        [self.selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];
        PickTaskTableviewCell *cell= [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.message.hidden=false;
        cell.messageLabel.text=[self pickTaskForIndexPath:indexPath].productSpecialMessage;
        cell.messageLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        cell.messageLabel.numberOfLines=3;
        if(cell.messageLabel.hidden==true){

            cell.messageLabel.hidden = false;
        } else {
            cell.messageLabel.hidden = true;
        }
        NSLog(@"message:%@",cell.messageLabel.text);
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }

    self.tableView.rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

***indexPath*** is added to the selectedIndexes on ***didSelectRowAtIndexPath***
Please help me

Comment: If the problem is with the label, please post the code that shows (hides) the label on selection (deselection).

Comment: added the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells should be configured only within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  When a state change occurs that makes a cell need to look different, just reload that cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PickTaskTableviewCell *cell = (PickTaskTableviewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // everything else you do to configure the cell goes here, then ...

    // check the logic here, we want one condition that tells us whether to show the labels
    if([[self cellIsSelected:indexPath] && self pickTaskForIndexPath:indexPath].productSpecialMessage){
        // don't need these here
        //NSNumber *selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isSelected];
        // [self.selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];
        // PickTaskTableviewCell *cell= [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.message.hidden=false;
        cell.messageLabel.text=[self pickTaskForIndexPath:indexPath].productSpecialMessage;
        cell.messageLabel.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        cell.messageLabel.numberOfLines=3;
        cell.messageLabel.hidden=NO;
    } else {
        cell.message.hidden=YES;
        cell.messageLabel.hidden=YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"message:%@",cell.messageLabel.text);
    // don't need this here
    // [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Selection (and presumably deselection) cause the need to update the cell, so...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // don't deselect it here, just reload it

    // more on this later...
    [self.selectedIndexes setObject:selectedIndex forKey:indexPath];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

// probably do the same in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
```

One last (optional) point.  There's no need to maintain your own list of selected index paths, `UITableView` does that for you, so you could delete your `selectedIndexes` property and just use the table view methods, e.g....

```
- (BOOL)cellIsSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return whether the cell at the specified index path is selected or not
    return [[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] containsObject:indexPath];
}
```